# Add Member to MongoDB Replica Set, from the member's side

Tags: mongodb, replication, master-slave, replicaset

Let's suppose i have a Replica Set (Master and a bunch of slaves)! I want to automate the fact that a new mongodb node can be selfRegistered to the ReplicaSet without knowing who is the master, and without connecting to it.

Is it possible to add a new member to a MongoDB Replica Set without executing the rs.add() shell command (from the primary node's side) ?

Is it possible for the member to register itself to the Replica Set using some special parameters ? maybe some kind of authentication !

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add a new member to a MongoDB Replica Set without executing the rs.add() shell command (from the primary node's side) ?

It is possible, you can execute [rs.reconfig()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/#rs.reconfig) with `force` option from a [secondary member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-secondary/). Although note that using `rs.reconfig()` with `{ force: true }` can lead to [rollback](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-rollback) of committed writes. Consider also a case where due to network partition you're connecting to a member that couldn't see to the majority of the replica set members.

A safer way would be to connect to any replica set member, determine the primary member via [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/) and execute [rs.add()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.add/) via the primary of replica set.

See also [database command isMaster()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#dbcmd.isMaster)

> Is it possible for the member to register itself to the Replica Set using some special parameters ?

As of MongoDB v3.4.x, this is currently not possible. For various reasons, ensuring only the primary member that could alter the [Replica Set Configuration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/) for consistency between members is important.